# Tensorflow Mirror Strategy and Horovod Distribution Strategy

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mpi, distributed-tensorflow, horovod

I am trying to understand what are the basic difference between Tensorflow Mirror Strategy and Horovod Distribution Strategy.

From the documentation and the source code investigation I found that Horovod (https://github.com/horovod/horovod) is using Message Passing Protocol (MPI) to communicate between multiple nodes. Specifically it uses all_reduce, all_gather of MPI.

From my observation (I may be wrong) Mirror Strategy is also using all_reduce algorithm (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute).

Both of them are using data-parallel, synchronous training approach. 
So I am a bit confused how they are different? Is the difference only in implementation or there are other (theoretical) difference?

And how is the performance of mirror strategy compared to horovod?

Comment: Take a look https://www.logicalclocks.com/goodbye-horovod-hello-tensorflow-collectiveallreduce/

Answer (score 0):

Mirror Strategy has its own all_reduce algorithm which use remote procedural calls (gRPC) under the hood.

Like you mentioned Horovod uses MPI/GLOO to communicate between multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the performance, one of my colleagues have performed experiments before using 4 Tesla V100 GPUs using the codes from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/allreduce.py). The results suggested that 3 settings work the best: `replicated` with `all_reduce_spec=nccl`, `collective_all_reduce` with properly tuned `allreduce_merge_scope` (e.g. 32), and `horovod`. I did not see significant differences among these 3.